# Multiple NFT meta in the tx_metadata.json of a single asset?

Tags: nft, cardano-db-sync, metadata

In some, not all cases, when I retrieve the tx_metadata.json of a given fingerprint (of an NFT), the json contains the meta of several NFT's, redundantly.
I cannot seem to see any sensible way of being certain which of them belongs to the asset who's metadata I am querying if the asset name is not itself in the meta data, as is the case, for example, in adahandles.

It is not this way for all assets, many, if not most, have a single meta data object, as one might expect.

If there are multiples though, firstly...why? Secondly, how do I know which meta data object to extract from the multiple objects in the tx_metadata.json field of a single asset?